# Как создать гиперссылку в комментариях?

Tags: поддержка

Видел гиперссылки в комментариях, но не знаю, как их создавать самому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайтах сети Stack Exchange для оформления вопросов и ответов используется разметка Markdown, а в комментариях ее упрощенный вариант. Подробнее про возможностях разметки на сайте можно посмотреть в [справочном центре](/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Эврика!

Кв. скобка + foo + Кв. скобка + круглая скобка + http://foo.com + круглая скобка

Результат здесь и в комментарии:

[foo](http://foo.com)

Comment: [foo](http://foo.com)